(MacOS) Is it possible to have two Blender Instances (especially with working addons?)
Question
How do I open up two instances of Blender with both of them working with addons?
Context

I come from a Windows 11 background, where it is possible to do the above question in this environment
I understand how to create two instances of Blender via Terminal
After making two instances of Blender, one of the instances do not have working addons.

I use Better Pie Addons, and realized the instance that was opened first have the addons working while the second instance that was opened later does not.



Intention

I have a Main and an Experimental/Tutorial instance.

In my current case, I wish to reference the shaders nodes that I have done for the tutorial since the connection are very complicated
Sure, taking a screenshot is nice, but since I only have one screen, it is nice for me to scroll around the shader screen!



Theory

Is the second instance of Blender reading the same addon file? Does that mean I need to specify another configuration file? I assume that some resources (such as the addon) are locked in read, write and execute?

Conclusion

Thank you in advance for those who choose to help me!
I am really new to the Mac ecosystem so any help will be greatly appreciated!

References
This similar question seemed to already have been answered a long time ago but was wondering if anyone has any updates to this! Here is the link below:
Is it possible to work on two or more files at the same time (or open multiple Blender instances?)

You can have multiple separate Blender.app, which can be launched independently, but you’ll need to install add-ons separately in both.

@Phrogz Thank you very much for your helpful reply! You are right, I was able to copy and paste another Blender application and it worked flawlessly!

Hi @DuarteFarrajotaRamos and thank you for correction suggestions. May I ask of you to check if everything is in order?


Thank you @Phrogz for your helpful solution!

Summary
Duplicate Blender in the Application window and rename.
Workflow

Navigate to Applications


Locate Blender application, copy/paste and rename.


It is now possible to open two isolated Blender applications! Have fun! (Note: You may need to reinstall and re-enable your addons)


